# select specific columns from eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am attempting to select the specific columns in the bottom select portion but cannot get the syntax correct nor can i find any post of a similar style of problem. If this were straight sql with table aliases it would be no problem. I'm obviously missing a concept here somewhere?

```
Job::has('contractSite.contract.quote')
        ->with('task.siteTaskVisit.siteTask.quoteTask.task.taskGroup')
        ->with('task.siteTaskVisit.siteTask.quoteTask.totalPrice')
        ->with('task.siteTaskVisit')
        ->with('contractSite.site')
        ->with('contractSite.contract.quote.owner')
        ->with('contractSite.contract.quote.salesRegion')
        ->with('contractSite.contract.quote.client')
        ->with('contractSite.contract.quote.type')
        ->with('contractSite.contract.quote.productGroup')
        ->select([
            'contractSite.contract.quote.salesRegion.name as Region',
            'contractSite.contract.quote.owner.name as Rep',
            'contractSite.contract.quote.type.name as Type',
            'created_at as Created',
            'task.siteTaskVisit.at as Pledged',
            'internal_reference as Job',
            'contractSite.contract.quote.productGroup.summary as ProductGroup',
            'task.siteTaskVisit.siteTask.quoteTask.totalPrice as Balance',
            'task.site_task_visit.site_task.quote_task.task.task_group.code as TaskCodes'
        ])
        ->get();
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You may need to watch the `created_at`. If you have that field on multiple tables, you'll need to specify which table.created_at you want

Comment: its a syntax error as below, The created at field is the only one so shouldn't be an issue

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`salesRegion`.`name` as `Region`, ...........

goes on for quite a while

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use relations as joins. If you just want a flat list of results instead of nested relationships, then change it to joins. If you want the results in a nested relationship, then you'll need to use closures on each `with` to get the columns you want, as long as you also specify the necessary keys for each relationship.

Comment: thank you for the reply and help.